# Filter a CSV daily and get the diferences between the last day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I'm working with a supplier who gives me daily a CSV with the stock updates. I need to upload it to my cms website with an import tool. That is cool to make everything faster, but I got some problems:

- The CSV provided isn't in the same configuration as the import tool.
  No problem here, I did a filter with a simple Query and Importrange getting exactly the columns I need.
- The categorization from the supplier is bad, so, I need to automatic list the categories and make my own. 
  No problem here, I did a `=UNIQUE` with the categories and I wrote my own categories. After that, with a simple vlookup, I get a Column with the right categories.

Now, I have my own CSV filter, so I can upload it so fast.

But now, I have a bigger problem. I need to update the stocks from website, and add the new products.

My cms works with Refer Number to update, so, I just need to generate a CSV with the products to update, and import it. And for the new products, also the same, I just need to found the new products and import them.

The problem here is, how can I get the changes from stock and the new products?

I tried to save all CSV in the same sheet to get the differences between the last ones, but we are talking about 9k rows per sheet, so, that gives me some issues.

I have some ideas, like, use a filter document for every new CSV file, and compare better the filtered sheets than the raw CSV.

But I need to do it with efficiency because its something to do daily.

I don't need a code or something like that, just some ideas to follow a way. I can search, learn and understand most of the things, so, this is not a problem.

I have an example here for my filter document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jfq1h4gnKbdoKrI7J260lXXKzXbkusbzn2cQcURPjCo/edit?usp=sharing

And If you need more from me, I can tell you everything.

Sorry about my English, I'm a Spanish guy and its still difficult for me to explain myself.

Comment: can you add the desired output in your example sheet? I'm reading through your question and can't rly say what are you asking

Comment: Sorry If I cant explain my self.

Comment: Imagine something simple like, I have a CSV every day with some updates, with that CSV's, I need my two own CSV, one with new products, and the other one, with stock changes. Make sense?

Comment: Welcome. Would you please edit your spreadsheet to include an example of the CSV for your CMS.

Comment: You are trying to address the issue of "changes from stock and the new products". I understand that this means 1) if the supplier has new products, then you want to add those to the CMS, and 2) for all products on the CMS, you want to update the latest stock quantities. Would you please explain the meaning of your filter conditions ("Min-Qty-to-sell=1" and "Available=Yes") in terms of the products that appear on the CMS?

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, thanks for your help! I will add a sheet in the spread with the example of CSV. I named it as "CSV EXAMPLE". 

And about your points, yes, you are right.

Comment: About your question, Min Quantity to sell, its because some product you need to buy for example 10 of them. I mean, you cannot buy 1, you need 10 per buy. 

And about Available, it's only if you want your product Active or not.

Comment: @Tedinoz its clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two CSV files that have been imported into Google Sheets. One is from your supplier with stock details for new and existing products; you have filtered this to obtain data in the correct format. The other is from your CMS - it is an output of the current CMS data.

You want to check that all new products are added to the CMS, and that stock details of all existing products are updated to the CMS. You might also choose to check that all products on the CMS are on the supplier list, and that the Minimum-to-Sell-Quantity remains equal to one.

The following code is untested but reflects a suggested strategy. I apologise if I have misunderstood your intentions.

- Using the Javascript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, create a list of all reference numbers in the CMS.
- Using the Javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method, loop through the values in the filtered Supplier data and check every reference number to the CMS list.

  - where the number exists on the CMS list - this is an existing product, so update stock
  - where the number does not exist on the CMS list - this is a new product, so create the new product in the CMS.

As a double check, you might reverse the process to ensure that i) every number on the CMS list exists on the filtered Supplier list and ii) that the "Minimum-Quantity-to-Sell" is still one unit. Those CMS products that can't be found on the Supplier list could be written to an error sheet and reviewed.

---

```
function so5836302201() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cmsname = "CSV EXAMPLE";
  var cms = ss.getSheetByName(cmsname);
  var filtername = "FILTER"
  var filter = ss.getSheetByName(filtername);
  var cmserrorsname = "cms errors";
  var cmserrors = ss.getSheetByName(errorsname);

  // get cms data
  var cmsLR = cms.getLastRow();
  var cmsLC = cms.getLastColumn();
  var cmsRange = cms.getRange(2,1,cmsLR-1,cmsLC);
  var cmsValues = cmsRange.getValues();

  // get filter data
  var filterLR = filter.getLastRow();
  var filterLC = filter.getLastColumn();
  var filterRange = filter.getRange(2,1,cmsLR-1,cmsLC);
  var filterValues = filterRange.getValues();

  // setup cms errors sheet


  // "My cms works with Refer Number to update"
  // check every product from filter to cms
  // if not exist in cms; then update cms as new 
  // if exist in cms, then update cms for stock

  // cms reference number: assume the reference number is in column E of the cms=> column 4(zero-based)
  // cms reference number: assume the reference number is in column B of the filter=> column 1(zero-based)

  // get an array of reference numbers from the CMS
  var cmsRefNum = cmsValues.map(function(e){return e[4];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  //Logger.log(cmsRefNum); // DEBUG


  // loop though filter and find ref num in cms
  for (var i = 0;i<filterValues.length;i++){

    Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", Filter Ref Num: "+filterValues[i][1])

    var filterresult = cmsValues.indexOf(filterValues[i][1]);
    if (filterresult === -1){
      // -1 means this is a new product
      // include cope to add this product to cms
    }
    else{
      // if not -1, the Filter product exists on cms
      // include code to update stock only    
      // you might also test that Suppliers Min-Qty-to-Sell remains = 1
    }

  }

  // belt and braces
  // loop through cms and ensure that stock item was on filter.
  var filterRefNum = filterValues.map(function(e){return e[1];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  //Logger.log(filterRefNum); // DEBUG
  var cmsmissingdata=[]
  for (var i=0;i<cmsValues.length;i++){
    var cmstemp=[];
    Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", CMS Ref Num: "+cmsValues[i][4])
    var cmsresult = filterValues.indexOf(cmsValues[i][4]);
    if (cmsresult === -1){
      // -1 means this product wasn't on the Filter 
      // include this product on an error report.
      cmstemp.push(filterValues[i][0]);
      cmstemp.push(filterValues[i][1]);
      cmstemp.push(filterValues[i][2]);
      cmsmissingdata.push(cmstemp);
    }

    // delete existing cmserrors
    var errorsLR = cmserrors.length;
    var errorsLC = 3;
    var errorsRange = cmserrors.getRange(2,1,errorsLR,errorsLC);
    errorsRange.clearContent();


    if (cmserrors.length !=0){
      // there are errors - write them to 
      var errorsLR = cmserrors.length;
      var errorsLC = 3;
      var errorsRange = cmserrors.getRange(2,1,cmsLR-1,cmsLC);
      cmserrors.setValues(cmsmissingdata);
    }
  }

}
```